# removing bias/noise from gappy signal

Tags: signal-processing

I have an array of soil water content sensors across several desert field sites.  Their signals contain a lot of noise or bias (depending on who I talk to).  I want to remove the junk while keeping as much of the signal as possible.  I'm not a signal processing guy, so anything along the lines of "use an XYZ filter" or a particular algorithm or something would really help me.

I've posted a plot showing a year's worth of data from one probe.  The signal is the "top"; all the junk is below the signal:
http://www.unm.edu/~hilton/swc.png

I've played around with lowess smoothing a lot; that works reasonably well except in places where there's a lot of bias below the signal (like roughly idx 1000 to 2000 and 15000 to 16000 in the example below).

I have access to Matlab's signal processing toolbox and I'm very comfortable in R and python; if there's a pre-packaged filter in one of those I could jump off from that would be great (but I'm open to coding something new).

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a median filter.  If I read your plot correctly you're sampling twice an hour and the data isn't too dynamic.  Assuming that's correct, a median filter length of 47 or 49 would equate to a one-day window.  In this data set you could probably crank that up to a week or more.  In any case you should plot the unfiltered and filtered data on top of each other to make sure the filtered data passes the eyeball test (you'll know it when you see it).  You may need to do the final clean-up by hand (hope you don't have thousands of sensors).

(Also, I'd send an intern or grad student out to the field sites to find out what's wrong with  sensors and fix them.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth a quick try to implement some standard deviation filtering of your data set. Split your data up into N segments and for each segment, calculate the standard deviation for the Y-values. Once you've got that, filter out data points that have Y-values that exceed 3 standard deviations (or however much you want). Of course, there is some manual work that goes on with figuring out exactly how many segments to use.